# How to alter a character in a string in java

Tags: java, input

```
Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
String str=s.nextLine();
str.charAt(2)='a';
```

I have used substr function . but can it be done without it? Why is this statement incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are immutable in JAVA. You can convert it to a Character Array and then alter the characters.

```
String str = s.nextLine();
char[] chrArray = str.toCharArray();
chrArray[2] = 'a';
```

If you want a String out of it then you can do:

```
String finalStr = new String(chrArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setCharAt` like this:

```
  StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder(str);
    string.setCharAt(2, 'a');
```

Or `char[]` array:

```
  char[] nameChars = str.toCharArray();
  nameChars[2] = 'a';
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong then it should be`StringBuilder myName = new StringBuilder(str);` instead of `StringBuilder myName = new StringBuilder("str");`

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder sb =new StringBuilder(str);
    System.out.println(" string is : "+sb.replace(2, 3, "a"));
```

sb.replace(start index,endindex,replace string)
start index ;- string start index
end index ;- end index for example if you want to replace single char then start 2 and end 3